# Difference in query execution plan between MySQL 5.5.54 and mariadb 5.5.56

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, execution-plan

I am executing a `SELECT` on 2 Hosts, "old db" running `mysql 5.5.54` and "new db" running `mariadb 5.5.56`. Both the runtime and the `EXPLAIN` show a difference, with the mariadb being significantly slower. The data on "new db" is a very recent dump of "old db"

**EXPLAIN on "old db"**:

```
explain SELECT 
    b.tariff as tariff, b.benefitType as benefitType, b.name as name,
    b.code as code, SUM(b.effQuantPckType) as `count`, 
    SUM(effCalcAmtVat) as `amount`, 
    SUM(effAmt) as `amountAL`, SUM(effAmt2) as `amountTL`  
FROM 
    benefitCombined AS b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice AS inv ON inv.id = b.invoice  
WHERE (invoicePart != 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' OR invoice != 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
  AND executingDoctor = 'dqwjvgbskiaaaacsonmj'
  AND b.begin >= '2018-06-16 00:00:00' AND 
      b.begin <= '2018-07-16 23:59:57'
  AND 1=1 
GROUP BY 
    benefitType, code;

+----+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table         | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      | 287344 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | invoiceBase   | eq_ref | id            | id   | 20      | b.invoice |      1 | Using index                                  |
|  2 | DERIVED      | benefitBase   | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      | 285328 | Using where                                  |
|  3 | UNION        | benefitTarmed | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      |      1 | Using where                                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3>    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      |   NULL |                                              |
+----+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (3.34 sec)
```

**SHOW CREATE on "old db"**:

```
show create table invoice \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: invoice
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`c0515_dwh`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `invoice` AS (
select  `invoiceBase`.`id` AS `id`,`invoiceBase`.`created` AS `created`,
    `invoiceBase`.`begin` AS `begin`,`invoiceBase`.`end` AS `end`,
    `invoiceBase`.`formatType` AS `formatType`,`invoiceBase`.`invUID` AS `invUID`,
    `invoiceBase`.`traStat` AS `traStat`,`invoiceBase`.`invStat` AS `invStat`,
    `invoiceBase`.`patient` AS `patient`,`invoiceBase`.`provider` AS `provider`,
    `invoiceBase`.`biller` AS `biller`,`invoiceBase`.`debitor` AS `debitor`,
    `invoiceBase`.`name` AS `name`,`invoiceBase`.`amtDue` AS `amtDue`,
    `invoiceBase`.`law` AS `law`,`invoiceBase`.`reason` AS `reason`,
    `invoiceBase`.`amtTotal` AS `amtTotal`,`invoiceBase`.`amtPrepaid` AS `amtPrepaid`,
    `invoiceBase`.`amtPaid` AS `amtPaid`,`invoiceBase`.`amtPaidDirect` AS `amtPaidDirect`,
    `invoiceBase`.`amtFee` AS `amtFee`,`invoiceBase`.`splitFac` AS `splitFac`,
    `invoiceBase`.`invoiceType` AS `invoiceType`,`invoiceBase`.`invoiceOptimal` AS `invoiceOptimal`,
    `invoiceBase`.`patientCopy` AS `patientCopy`,`invoiceBase`.`diagnoses` AS `diagnoses`,
    `invoiceBase`.`customerNumber` AS `customerNumber`,`invoiceBase`.`traStatDate` AS `traStatDate`,
    `invoiceBase`.`invStatDate` AS `invStatDate`,`invoiceBase`.`oldInvoiceNr` AS `oldInvoiceNr`,
    `invoiceBase`.`newInvoiceNr` AS `newInvoiceNr`,`invoiceBase`.`mandator` AS `mandator`,
    `invoiceBase`.`account` AS `account`,`invoiceBase`.`cancReqFlag` AS `cancReqFlag`,
    `invoiceBase`.`cancReqDate` AS `cancReqDate`,`invoiceBase`.`claimNr` AS `claimNr`,
    `invoiceBase`.`claimReqFlag` AS `claimReqFlag`,`invoiceBase`.`claimReqDate` AS `claimReqDate`,
    `invoiceBase`.`depReqFlag` AS `depReqFlag`,`invoiceBase`.`depReqDate` AS `depReqDate`,
    `invoiceBase`.`canton` AS `canton`,`invoiceBase`.`amtObligations` AS `amtObligations`,
    `invoiceBase`.`amtTax` AS `amtTax`,`invoiceBase`.`remarks` AS `remarks`,
    `invoiceBase`.`cancRemarks` AS `cancRemarks`,`invoiceBase`.`claimRemarks` AS `claimRemarks`,
    `invoiceBase`.`depRemarks` AS `depRemarks`,`invoiceBase`.`p02InvNr` AS `p02InvNr`,
    `invoiceBase`.`p02InvDate` AS `p02InvDate`,`invoiceBase`.`invoiceDate` AS `invoiceDate`,
`invoiceBase`.`debMngmt` AS `debMngmt`,
    (round(((`invoiceBase`.`amtTotal` * `invoiceBase`.`splitFac`) * 20),
                0) / 20) AS `calcAmtTotal`,round((`invoiceBase`.`amtPrepaid` * `invoiceBase`.`splitFac`),
                        2) AS `calcAmtPrepaid`,round((`invoiceBase`.`amtTax` * `invoiceBase`.`splitFac`),
                2) AS `calcAmtTax`,round((`invoiceBase`.`amtObligations` * `invoiceBase`.`splitFac`),
        2
    ) AS `calcAmtObligations`,
        2) + `invoiceBase`.`amtPaid`) + `invoiceBase`.`amtPaidDirect`) AS `calcAmtPaid`,

character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
```

...

```
show create table benefitCombined \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                View: benefitCombined
         Create View: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`c0515_dwh`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `benefitCombined` AS (
select  `benefitBase`.`id` AS `id`,`benefitBase`.`additionType` AS `additionType`,
    `benefitBase`.`end` AS `end`,`benefitBase`.`eanExecuting` AS `eanExecuting`,
    `benefitBase`.`eanResponsible` AS `eanResponsible`,`benefitBase`.`unitFac` AS `unitFac`,
    `benefitBase`.`extFac` AS `extFac`,`benefitBase`.`amountQty1` AS `amountQty1`,
    `benefitBase`.`orderNumber` AS `orderNumber`,`benefitBase`.`srvAtts` AS `srvAtts`,
    `benefitBase`.`tariff` AS `tariff`,`benefitBase`.`benefitType` AS `benefitType`,
    `benefitBase`.`code` AS `code`,`benefitBase`.`executingDoctor` AS `executingDoctor`,
    `benefitBase`.`responsibleDoctor` AS `responsibleDoctor`,
    `benefitBase`.`obligation` AS `obligation`,`benefitBase`.`refCode` AS `refCode`,
    `benefitBase`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,`benefitBase`.`effQuant` AS `effQuant`,
    `benefitBase`.`begin` AS `begin`,`benefitBase`.`unit` AS `unit`,
    `benefitBase`.`scaleFac` AS `scaleFac`,`benefitBase`.`amount` AS `amount`,
    `benefitBase`.`effAmt` AS `effAmt`,`benefitBase`.`vatRate` AS `vatRate`,
    `benefitBase`.`negObligation` AS `negObligation`,`benefitBase`.`sessionNr` AS `sessionNr`,
    `benefitBase`.`pckMult` AS `pckMult`,`benefitBase`.`pckType` AS `pckType`,
    `benefitBase`.`pckUnits` AS `pckUnits`,`benefitBase`.`srvMin` AS `srvMin`,
    `benefitBase`.`name` AS `name`,`benefitBase`.`invoicePart` AS `invoicePart`,
    `benefitBase`.`created` AS `created`,`benefitBase`.`session` AS `session`,
    `benefitBase`.`patient` AS `patient`,`benefitBase`.`medicalCase` AS `medicalCase`,
    `benefitBase`.`invoice` AS `invoice`,`benefitBase`.`owner` AS `owner`,
    0 AS `unitFac2`,0 AS `extFac2`,0 AS `amount2Qty1`,NULL AS `bodyLoc`,
    0 AS `unit2`,0 AS `scaleFac2`,0 AS `amount2`,0 AS `effAmt2`,
    `benefitBase`.`amount` AS `calcAmtVat`,`benefitBase`.`effAmt` AS `effCalcAmtVat`,
            (`benefitBase`.`amount` / (1 + (`benefitBase`.`vatRate` / 100))) AS `calcAmtWoVat`,
            (`benefitBase`.`effAmt` / (1 + (`benefitBase`.`vatRate` / 100))) AS `effCalcAmtWoVat`,
NULL AS `calcMinTot`,NULL AS `effCalcMinTot`,
ifnull(round((`benefitBase`.`effAmt` / nullif(`benefitBase`.`amountQty1`,
                                0)),3),0
      ) AS `effQuantPckType` from  `benefitBase`
    where  (((`benefitBase`.`invoicePart` <> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
                      and  (`benefitBase`.`invoicePart` is not null))
              or  ((`benefitBase`.`invoice` <> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
                      and  (`benefitBase`.`invoice` is not null))
           )
    )
UNION all (
SELECT  `benefitTarmed`.`id` AS `id`,`benefitTarmed`.`additionType` AS `additionType`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`end` AS `end`,`benefitTarmed`.`eanExecuting` AS `eanExecuting`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`eanResponsible` AS `eanResponsible`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`unitFac` AS `unitFac`,`benefitTarmed`.`extFac` AS `extFac`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`amountQty1` AS `amountQty1`,`benefitTarmed`.`orderNumber` AS `orderNumber`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`srvAtts` AS `srvAtts`,`benefitTarmed`.`tariff` AS `tariff`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`benefitType` AS `benefitType`,`benefitTarmed`.`code` AS `code`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`executingDoctor` AS `executingDoctor`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`responsibleDoctor` AS `responsibleDoctor`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`obligation` AS `obligation`,`benefitTarmed`.`refCode` AS `refCode`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,`benefitTarmed`.`effQuant` AS `effQuant`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`begin` AS `begin`,`benefitTarmed`.`unit` AS `unit`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`scaleFac` AS `scaleFac`,`benefitTarmed`.`amount` AS `amount`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`effAmt` AS `effAmt`,`benefitTarmed`.`vatRate` AS `vatRate`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`negObligation` AS `negObligation`,`benefitTarmed`.`sessionNr` AS `sessionNr`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`pckMult` AS `pckMult`,`benefitTarmed`.`pckType` AS `pckType`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`pckUnits` AS `pckUnits`,`benefitTarmed`.`srvMin` AS `srvMin`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`name` AS `name`,`benefitTarmed`.`invoicePart` AS `invoicePart`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`created` AS `created`,`benefitTarmed`.`session` AS `session`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`patient` AS `patient`,`benefitTarmed`.`medicalCase` AS `medicalCase`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`invoice` AS `invoice`,`benefitTarmed`.`owner` AS `owner`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`unitFac2` AS `unitFac2`,`benefitTarmed`.`extFac2` AS `extFac2`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`amount2Qty1` AS `amount2Qty1`,`benefitTarmed`.`bodyLoc` AS `bodyLoc`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`unit2` AS `unit2`,`benefitTarmed`.`scaleFac2` AS `scaleFac2`,
    `benefitTarmed`.`amount2` AS `amount2`,`benefitTarmed`.`effAmt2` AS `effAmt2`,
        (`benefitTarmed`.`amount` + `benefitTarmed`.`amount2`) AS `calcAmtVat`,
        (`benefitTarmed`.`effAmt` + `benefitTarmed`.`effAmt2`) AS `effCalcAmtVat`,
        ((`benefitTarmed`.`amount` + `benefitTarmed`.`amount2`) / (1 + (`benefitTarmed`.`vatRate` / 100))) AS `calcAmtWoVat`,
        ((`benefitTarmed`.`effAmt` + `benefitTarmed`.`effAmt2`) / (1 + (`benefitTarmed`.`vatRate` / 100))) AS `effCalcAmtWoVat`,
        (`benefitTarmed`.`srvMin` * `benefitTarmed`.`quantity`) AS `calcMinTot`,
        (`benefitTarmed`.`srvMin` * `benefitTarmed`.`effQuant`) AS `effCalcMinTot`,ifnull(round(((`benefitTarmed`.`effAmt` + `benefitTarmed`.`effAmt2`) / nullif((`benefitTarmed`.`amountQty1` + `benefitTarmed`.`amount2Qty1`),0)),3),0) AS `effQuantPckType`
from  `benefitTarmed`
where  (((`benefitTarmed`.`invoicePart` <> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
                  and  (`benefitTarmed`.`invoicePart` is not null)
              )
          or  ((`benefitTarmed`.`invoice` <> 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
                  and  (`benefitTarmed`.`invoice` is not null)))
      )
character_set_client: latin1
collation_connection: latin1_swedish_ci
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SHOW INDEX on "old db"**:

```
show index from benefitBase from c0515_dwh;
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                            | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| benefitBase |          0 | id                                  |            1 | id                | A         |      275913 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_created_index           |            1 | created           | A         |      275913 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_tariff_index            |            1 | tariff            | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_code_index              |            1 | code              | A         |          15 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_executingDoctor_index   |            1 | executingDoctor   | A         |         249 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_responsibleDoctor_index |            1 | responsibleDoctor | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_obligation_index        |            1 | obligation        | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_begin_index             |            1 | begin             | A         |       39416 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_negObligation_index     |            1 | negObligation     | A         |          13 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_name_index              |            1 | name              | A         |          17 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_owner_index             |            1 | owner             | A         |         226 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_patient_index           |            1 | patient           | A         |       30657 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitBase |          1 | benefitBase_session_index           |            1 | session           | A         |      275913 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

show index from benefitTarmed from c0515_dwh;
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name                              | Seq_in_index | Column_name       | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| benefitTarmed |          0 | id                                    |            1 | id                | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_created_index           |            1 | created           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_tariff_index            |            1 | tariff            | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_code_index              |            1 | code              | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_executingDoctor_index   |            1 | executingDoctor   | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_responsibleDoctor_index |            1 | responsibleDoctor | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_obligation_index        |            1 | obligation        | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_begin_index             |            1 | begin             | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_negObligation_index     |            1 | negObligation     | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_name_index              |            1 | name              | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_patient_index           |            1 | patient           | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| benefitTarmed |          1 | benefitTarmed_owner_index             |            1 | owner             | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+---------------------------------------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+

show index from invoiceBase from c0515_dwh;
+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table       | Non_unique | Key_name                         | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| invoiceBase |          0 | id                               |            1 | id             | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_created_index        |            1 | created        | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_begin_index          |            1 | begin          | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_end_index            |            1 | end            | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_traStat_index        |            1 | traStat        | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_invStat_index        |            1 | invStat        | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_patient_index        |            1 | patient        | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_provider_index       |            1 | provider       | A         |          34 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_biller_index         |            1 | biller         | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_name_index           |            1 | name           | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_law_index            |            1 | law            | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_reason_index         |            1 | reason         | A         |          25 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_amtPrepaid_index     |            1 | amtPrepaid     | A         |          73 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_amtPaid_index        |            1 | amtPaid        | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_amtPaidDirect_index  |            1 | amtPaidDirect  | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_amtFee_index         |            1 | amtFee         | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_invoiceType_index    |            1 | invoiceType    | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_invoiceOptimal_index |            1 | invoiceOptimal | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_patientCopy_index    |            1 | patientCopy    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_diagnoses_index      |            1 | diagnoses      | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_customerNumber_index |            1 | customerNumber | A         |          25 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_traStatDate_index    |            1 | traStatDate    | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_invStatDate_index    |            1 | invStatDate    | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_oldInvoiceNr_index   |            1 | oldInvoiceNr   | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_cancReqFlag_index    |            1 | cancReqFlag    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_cancReqDate_index    |            1 | cancReqDate    | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_claimNr_index        |            1 | claimNr        | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_claimReqFlag_index   |            1 | claimReqFlag   | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_claimReqDate_index   |            1 | claimReqDate   | A         |          19 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_depReqFlag_index     |            1 | depReqFlag     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_depReqDate_index     |            1 | depReqDate     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_cancRemarks_index    |            1 | cancRemarks    | A         |        2386 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_depRemarks_index     |            1 | depRemarks     | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_p02InvNr_index       |            1 | p02InvNr       | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_p02InvDate_index     |            1 | p02InvDate     | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_newInvoiceNr_index   |            1 | newInvoiceNr   | A         |        4508 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_mandator_index       |            1 | mandator       | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_account_index        |            1 | account        | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_invoiceDate_index    |            1 | invoiceDate    | A         |       40574 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| invoiceBase |          1 | invoiceBase_debMngmt_index       |            1 | debMngmt       | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------+------------+----------------------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**EXPLAIN on "new db"**

```
explain SELECT 
    b.tariff as tariff, b.benefitType as benefitType, b.name as name, b.code as code, SUM(b.effQuantPckType) as `count`, 
    SUM(effCalcAmtVat) as `amount`, 
    SUM(effAmt) as `amountAL`, SUM(effAmt2) as `amountTL`  
FROM 
    benefitCombined AS b 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN invoice AS inv ON inv.id = b.invoice  
WHERE 
    (invoicePart != 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' OR invoice != 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa') AND 
    executingDoctor = 'dqwjvgbskiaaaacsonmj' AND b.begin >= '2018-06-16 00:00:00' AND 
    b.begin <= '2018-07-16 23:59:57' AND 1=1 
GROUP BY 
    benefitType, code;

+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 281550 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    2 | DERIVED      | benefitBase   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 281549 | Using where                                  |
|    3 | UNION        | benefitTarmed | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |      1 | Using where                                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3>    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   NULL |                                              |
+------+--------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (5.53 sec)
```

**SHOW CREATE on "new db"**:

Identical to "old db".

I've done an "analyze table" on all tables / dbs on "new db" and also tried setting the same optimizer_switches, but the execution plan doesn't seem to change. mariadb.com mentions that "For all practical purposes, MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement of the same MySQL version...". My goal is to make the query execute at the same speed (at least) on "new db". I am looking for an explanation for the difference in the plans show above.

Edit: I've added index / view creation info, but the character limit is reached. The indexes show a difference in cardinality only, eg:

```
benefitBase_owner_index (old db: 233, new db: 17)
invoiceBase_newInvoiceNr_index (old db: 4647, new db: 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting the optimizer_switch (in this case 'table_elimination=on' was to blame for the difference in the execution plan) in the mariadb config file the execution plan changed and now resembles the one seen from 'old db' :

```
+------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table         | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      | 306922 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | invoiceBase   | eq_ref | id            | id   | 20      | b.invoice |      1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|    2 | DERIVED      | benefitBase   | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      | 306921 | Using where                                  |
|    3 | UNION        | benefitTarmed | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      |      1 | Using where                                  |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3>    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL      |   NULL |                                              |
+------+--------------+---------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-----------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I expected a change in execution time but the query still clocks in at about 6 seconds on a considerably faster (concerning CPU) host. As there might have been a difference in I/O speed or latency, i've mounted the tmpdir (which is used for writing the disk-bound temp tables) as a ramdisk, but there was no significant change in execution speed.

Answer (score 0):

Why did it change between versions?  Did the phase of the moon change?  I am only half joking.  `EXPLAIN` depends on "statistics" that are *approximate*.  Probably what happened is that the stats changed, leading to a different query plan.  And, since the Optimizer is not perfect, perhaps it misread the stats and picked the wrong index (or whatever).

5.5.54 is long after development ceased on 5.5; only critical bugs were being fixed.  So, I don't believe any deliberate changes were made in the Optimizer, only bug fixes.

Please learn the benefits of "composite" indexes.

```
  AND executingDoctor = 'dqwjvgbskiaaaacsonmj'
  AND b.begin >= '2018-06-16 00:00:00' AND 
      b.begin <= '2018-07-16 23:59:57'
```

begs for

```
INDEX(executingDoctor, `begin`)  -- in this order
```

This is assuming `executingDoctor` is in `b`.  Please qualify all columns when using a `JOIN`.  And provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Caveat: since a `VIEW` is involved, it may not be possible to make such an index and/or it may not get used.

Having dozens of indexes is usually a waste.  It is extremely likely that none of the indexes with Cardinality=1 will ever be used.  `DROP` them.  And probably those will 'small' cardinality are also unused.

`VIEWs` are still somewhat in their infancy in MySQL, especially back in 5.5.  Views are syntactic sugar around `SELECTs` and provide no performance benefit.  And *sometimes* they are not as well optimized.

For that kind of date range, consider

```
  AND b.begin >= '2018-06-16' AND 
  AND b.begin  < '2018-06-16' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Hmmm... `invoiceBase` is in the first `EXPLAIN` but not in the second.  Did the query change?  Did the row(s) needed from that able vanish?  After all it is a `LEFT JOIN`.